# angular pwa 8 ng serve refresh throws the error

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular8

I'm using pwa in my angular application, when ever I serve my application using `ng serve` refreshing the page cause `manifest.webmanifest not found`. Is there any workaround to prevent this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code in your index.html and also check the manifest file in your project. You can changes the extension of your manifest file to .json. It worked for me

`<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">`

Also, please check the MIME type of your response(should be application/manifest+json or application/json) based on file extension